# Swift style: Function returns optional of type that you need in order to continue, what's the best practice to handle this?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-binding

First, I'm going to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as my example since the de-queue function returns an optional and ignore the fact that it's perfectly safe to explicitly unwrap this.

**My question is**: what is considered the "best" way or style to handle a situation where you call a function that returns an optional but you need a return from this function to continue operation. This first snippet I find to be very clumsy and ugly:

```
if let theCell = UITableView().dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") {
    setUpCell(theCell)
    return theCell
  } else {
    let theCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    setUpCell(theCell)
    return theCell
}
```

Another option is:

```
let getNewCell = { return UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell") }
let cell = UITableView().dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") ?? getNewCell()
setUpCell(cell)
return cell
```

We escaped the tower of conditional optional binding with Swift 2 but I still find there to be a lack of an elegant way of dealing with optionals without going into braces.

Comment: If your goal is to remove braces, then don't wrap the new cell creation in a closure. Also, define "elegant".

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could write

```
var theCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
if theCell == nil { theCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell") }
setUpCell(theCell)
return theCell
```

However *in this case* the method which returns a non-optional is preferable

```
let theCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
setUpCell(theCell)
return theCell
```

And use also the passed `UITableView` instance.